# Just picked up the Odyssey G9 and can't change refresh rate on macbook pro

Tags: display, displayport

I'm using the DisplayPort that came with the monitor, along with a USB C -> DisplayPort adapter that apparently supports 4k; however, I can't seem to choose any refresh rates when selecting the "Scaled" option in the Display properties. I've held down the Option key while selecting Scaled and, although it gives me more options, the Refresh Rate is still greyed out. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

What exactly am I supposed to do in order to "enable" 60hz? The monitor supports 240hz but I can't seem to get past 60hz here. I've even tried to select 4k since the adapter seems to only support 4k, but it still doesn't become available.

The monitor settings are using 240hz (can only select between 240hz and 120hz because 60hz is greyed out). Guessing I can't use 240hz on the Macbook Pro, but not even 120hz?

Mac Specs:

MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017 edition)
macOS Big Sur
Version 11.4

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model of the adapter?

Comment: j5create. Just picked this up from MicroCenter: https://www.microcenter.com/product/466402/j5create-usb-31-(gen-2-type-c)-male-to-displayport-male-4k-cable-4-ft-white

Answer (score 1):

> The monitor settings are using 240hz (can only select between 240hz and 120hz because 60hz is greyed out).

I have MBP 16" 2019 + Odyssey NEO G9 and 60Hz is greyed out as well, but if I manually set the display to 120Hz, then the HDR option is vanished, but I can select 120Hz in macOS, and I can notice the difference. The scroll and all animations are more smooth. So far I was not able to set it to 240Hz.
If I set the display to 240hz, then the macOS will run at 60Hz, but HDR option is available, but somehow unusable although the colors are not washed out anymore since I upgraded the firmware of the display.

LE: with adaptive-sync disabled, the 60Hz option is not greyed out anymore